# How to exclude some values in MultipleChoiceField Django

Tags: python, django

This is my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.ManyToManyField(AnotherModel)
```

This is my view:

```
class MyModelView(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
```

Is it possible to exclude some values from multiple choice list in my view?
For example:
There are 10 positions in table AnotherModel but when updating MyModel I want only 5 values possible to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to) argument to `ManyToManyField`.

It works exactly similar to `limit_choices_to` argument in `ForeignKey`. You can check out examples given in in [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) documentation.